# invariance of $PSL_2(R)$ action on metric and volume $SH$ the unit tangent bundle of upper half plane $H\subset C$

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $SH$ be the unit tangent bundle of upper half plane defined by the pair $(z,\eta),z\in H,\eta\in C,|\eta|=Im(z)$. Define group action $SL_2(R)$ on $SH$ by $g=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\in SL_2(R), g(z,\eta)=(g(z),\frac{\eta}{(cz+d)^2})$. On $H$ there is a canonical hyperbolic metric $ds$ and volume $dv$ invariant under $SL_2(R)$ action.

Consider $\phi=\frac{1}{2\pi}Arg(\eta)$ where $\eta$ is defined as before as an element of $S^1$.

Define $dv'=dvd\phi$ and $ds'=\sqrt{ds^2+d\phi^2}$. I knew $ds^2$ and $dv$ part invariant under $SL_2(R)$ action for sure. Then the author claims $dv'$ and $ds'$ are invariant under $SL_2(R)$ action.

If I take a path on $SH$(i.e. $(z(t),\eta(t))$ parametrized by $t$ on $SH$), then $T\eta(t)=\frac{\eta(t)}{(cz(t)+d)^2}$ for $T=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. Now there is possible change of argument of $cz(t)+d$ part. If I take argument it should become $Arg(\eta(t))-2Arg(cz(t)+d)$. There is no reason that second term should not contribute if I take $\frac{d}{dt}$ acting upon.

Q: What have I done wrong here? I feel something wrong with my understanding here. I should have $\frac{d\phi}{dt}$ invariant.

Comment: It is very hard to tell what is it that you are proving. Are you proving that $SL(2,R)$ preserves the hyperbolic metric on the upper half-plane?

Comment: @MoisheCohen I want to show the induced metric on $SH$ is preserved under $SL_2(R)$ action. I knew metric on upper half plane is invariant under $SL_2(R)$ action. I need to show $d\phi$ invariant under $SL_2(R)$ action. However, I do not see it is invariant.

Comment: Of course $d\phi$ is not invariant. A general formalism is that given a Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$, you also have the Levi-Civita connection on the tangent bundle. This connection will be invariant under all isometries of $M$. Using this connection you get a canonical splitting of $TTM$ which allows you to lift (invariantly) the metric $g$ from $M$ to a metric $\tilde{g}$ on $TM$ and, hence, on $SM$.  Since the metric on fibers of $SM$ is $Isom(M)$-invariant (by definition!), so is the metric $\tilde{g}$.

Comment: @user45765 did you figure this out? i been trying to do it for like a week now :'(